How to format "custom" JSON output
I have a vendor that is expecting the response of a Web API GET request to look exactly like in the attached screenshot. I am using ASP.NET Web.API but I'm not using Entity Framework.
The data is being retrieved from a SQL Server stored procedure. I am not having any issues retrieving the data but cannot figure out a way to format the data as shown: I have tried using SQL Server FOR JSON, creating multiple tables and joining them but in every case the cartId etc. is repeated instead of being displayed once and the rest of the data nested as required?
I have tried returning the data in a single data table, multiple data tables, a single dataset a list, an array etc. but in all cases the format is not correct.


what have you tried?  what's not working? share some of your code for help

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The most idiomatic way to return JSON is to define an object model consisting of one or (in this case almost certainly) more Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) that model what the JSON document should look like.
In this case it looks as though you'll need a root class like this (assuming that cart is the appropriate name for the root):
public class CartDto
{
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public string CartCurrency { get; set; }
    public ContactDetailsDto[] ContactDetails { get; set; }
    public LineItemDto[] LineItems { get; set; }
    public ShopperCheckoutExperienceDto ShopperCheckoutExperience { get; set; }
}

As implied here, you're also going to need corresponding ContactDetailsDto, LineItemDto, and ShopperCheckoutExperienceDto classes, and probably even more than those for further nesting.
You'll then need to figure out how to transform your database data into such an object graph.
You may refer to my recent article series Three data architectures for the server for more details.
